# Error: Connection refused connecting to locahost - Berkshelf - Test Kitchen

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen, inspec, kitchen-dokken

I having an issue when running `kitchen converge` on Test Kitchen with `Dokken driver` and `Inspec` as verifier.

The error occurred when the starting to resolving the cookbook dependencies 7.0.6

`Resolving cookbook dependencies with Berkshelf 7.0.6...
[2019-06-18T15:17:56+08:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://localhost/cookbooks/apache2/3.1.0, retry 1/5
[2019-06-18T15:17:56+08:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://localhost/cookbooks/alternatives/0.1.1, retry 1/5
[2019-06-18T15:18:01+08:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://localhost/cookbooks/apache2/3.1.0, retry 2/5
[2019-06-18T15:18:01+08:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://localhost/cookbooks/alternatives/0.1.1, retry 2/5`

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding the new parameter inside the `~/.chef/knife.rb`, `chef_server_url 'https://chef-server-url'`